# Spring webservice with existing WSDL

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

I have a WSDL with 3 operations, and xsd schemas defined outside, 2 schemas for each operation (request + response) and a single Fault, same for all of the operations. It looks like this:

```html
src/main/resources/wsdl/transactions
-TransactionsOperations.wsdl
-FindTransactionRequest.xsd
-FindTransactionResponse.xsd
-RemoveTransactionRequest.xsd
...
-FaultMessage.xsd
```

It all works on Weblogic at the moment, but I wanted to try it with Spring. I can't get it to work tho. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-ws-soap-web-service-consumer-provider-wsdl-example.html) step by step. Ok, wsdl is indeed visible in the browser after going to `localhost:8080/ws/TransactionsOperations.wsdl`, but when I import it to SoapUI it fails on schema resolving (and no wonder, because they are not there). Schemas are in the same folder as WSDL, but they are not deployed for some reason.

I'm doing it exactly like in the tutorial, except that my schemas are defined externally and not inlined in WSDL and I think that's the whole problem here. They are imported in WSDL with `<xsd:import schemaLocation="FaultMessage.xsd"...`. Seems to me like Spring is not checking those imports, but I have not found any way to tell him about them (`SimpleWsdl11Definition` has only a single method `setWsdl`...). Is this even possible to do it that way in Spring, or I have to let Spring generate WSDL for me while only supplying schemas?

I tried giving him the schemas and letting him generate WSDL for me, but it didn't work either (I tried using `setSchemaCollection` on `DefaultWsdl11Definition`, it generated basically a 2-line empty WSDL). Only way I got it to work was to combine all of the schemas to a single XSD and doing it according to [Spring official tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/), and this is something I simply can't do, it becomes a mess with multiple operations.

Kind of a side problem: when I imported that working solution to SoapUI, the requests/responses had namespaces before each xml element, is it possible to get rid of those? (for example `<ns:id>1</ns:id>` in request, or `<ns2:accountNumber>123</ns2:accountNumber>`). That doesn't happen with Weblogic implementation.

/edit

Found 2 issues on Spring jira regarding this:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-281
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-346
and apparently it's been fixed, but I can't get it to work.

[Here](http://www.mytechtip.com/2012/09/static-wsdl-with-imported-xml-schema-in.html) I found the way to resolve this issue, but only with a single schema and I got a bunch of them.

Comment: XSD isn't WSDL... Hence `WsdlDefinition` won't work.. the `XsdSchema` class however is very suitable for that for instance the `SimpleXsdSchema`.

Comment: But I have both WSDL and XSD's, how can I give them both to Spring? `SimpleWsdl11Definition` accepts only WSDL, `DefaultWsdl11Definition` accepts only XSD's, because it wants to generate WSDL from them. Look at the first tutorial I posted, in WSDL there is `<wsdl:types>` with embedded XSD schema there, I have those schemas in separate files and Spring can't see them.

Comment: I added an edit regarding the jira issues about this problem and it's been fixed apparently (and really long time ago). Can you help @Arjen Poutsma? I hope marking users works here.

Comment: Have you read my comment? Register a `SimpleXsdSchema` one for each of the xsds.